# Workflow Service Application

Tags: c#, wcf

I am making workflow service for creating new request at HR system. 
The request is created successfully using the 'AddRequest' function as per the image below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/126V5.png

But When I want to get out argument of the request id, it gives error.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I call the WF service with new request activity and pass the Request Object.
the error when I try to get RequestID. ObjRequest is returned null.

What do I miss at the New Request Activity.

```
try
                {
                    objWFClient.NewRequest(ref objRequest);
                    bReqAdd = 1;
                    TempReqID = objRequest.nRequestID.ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed. The error was at Send reply to receive, the output argument must be same as in correlation handle.